# MATLAB: How to modify the dimension of a cell's matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, cell-array

I have a cell of matrices with the same number of columns and different number of rows

```
x = 

[210x15 double]  [220x15 double]   [236x15 double]
```

How can I reduce all matrices to the same minimum number of rows discarding them?
In this case it would be 210:

```
x = 

[210x15 double]  [210x15 double]   [210x15 double]
```

Comment: What do you mean by reduce? Simply discard the trailing rows?

Comment: Yes, i would to discard the trailing rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
cellfun(@(c) c(1:min(cellfun(@(c) size(c,1),x)),:),x,'uni',0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A primitive answer would be

```
rowcount = zeros(length(x),1);
for i = 1:length(x)
    rowcount(i) = size(x{i},1);
end
for i = 1:length(x)
    x{i}(min(rowcount)+1:end,:) = [];
end
```